# Combinatorics task

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I need help with a combinatorics task.

**In a convex octagon all diagonals are drawn, it is known that not any three of the diagonals cross at one point. Find the amount of the segments the octagon is separated into.**

I think I could solve it if each of those segments was a quadrilateral( I don't know if it's the case), then I'd find all the crossing points first, then I would find how many quadrilaterals they make up.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to define the octagon better.  If the octagon is regular (all sides equal and all angles equal), the four diagonals conecting opposite points all meet at the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a $n$-gon such that not any three of the diagonals cross at one point (which means that the $n$-gon is "very irregular"). Let us see how to answer your question. Suppose it is separated into $S_n$ pieces by all the diagonals.

If $n = 3$, there is no diagonal. Clearly $S_3 = 1$.

Suppose you already know $S_n$ for some $n \geq 3$. What can we do on $S_{n+1}$? Let us plug in a $(n+1)$-th vertex into the $n$-gon?

[image]

- The insertion of the new vertex gives a new triangle (add one piece).
- Now let us start to draw diagonals from the new vertex. If there are $k$ old vertices in the left of the diagonal and $n-1-k$ old vertices in the right of the diagonal. Then the diagonal intersects $k(n-1-k)$ old diagonals and gives $k(n-1-k)+1$ new segments. This means that

$$
\begin{aligned}
S_{n+1}-S_n &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} (k(n-1-k)+1)\\
&= (n-1) + (n-1)\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2} - \frac{(n-2)(n-1)(2n-3)}{6}\\
&= \frac{(n-1)(6+(n-2)n)}{6} = \frac{(n-1)(n^2 - 2n + 6)}{6}\\
S_n &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom k3 + (k-1) = \binom n4 + \binom {n-1}2.
\end{aligned}
$$